# Not able to Delete records on sysdate in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have been trying deleting records from a table which are of the current date that is sysdate in oracle. You can refer the below image where I tried

Tables Structure and inserted data
[image: Tables Structure and inserted data]

Querying Records
[image]

As you could see in the first image the type of updated_date is date. When I make an insert the data gets inserted with sysdate but when I try to select/delete it doesnt work in the second image.

At first, I thought maybe due to change in time may have caused this but the type is date and even I have tried to format it to dd-mon-yy so that shouldnt be the case

Comment: **NEVER**, ever call `to_date()` on a value that is already a date. That will first convert the `date` value to a `varchar` just to convert that `varchar` back to a `date` which it was to begin with.

Comment: You want `trunc(updated_date) = trunc(sysdate)`

Comment: i tried to_date because i thought change in time would be the reason so to_date(updated_date,'dd-mon-yy') should have worked but just din even gave a thought that left operand also needs a to_date(updated_date,'dd-mon-yy')/trunc as it got inserted

Comment: Again: **never** call `to_date()` with a parameter that is already a date (or timestamp). That is plain wrong.

Comment: yeah got your point I mean I should have used trunc on both sides and yes there is no point converting a date again via to_date(). thanks mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DATE` data type has time component, which is not displayed in your tool.

> [DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT413)
>
> The DATE datatype stores point-in-time values (dates and times) in a table. The DATE datatype stores the year (including the century), the month, the day, **the hours, the minutes, and the seconds (after midnight).**

You need to truncate both `SYSDATE` and `updated_date` columns.

```
SELECT * FROM EMPL WHERE TRUNC(updated_date) = TRUNC(SYSDATE);
```

To check "real value" you should change the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
SELECT * FROM EMPL;
```

Comment: Yes you are right I tried it on the right side of the comparison operator but not on left. Change in time is the only reason the value gets changed after you make an insert. Thanks!